# Access denied for user 'test_user'@'test_host' (using password: YES)

Tags: java, mysql

I have a mysql user called `test_user`

```
GRANT all privileges on *.* to 'test_user'@'%' identified by 'test_passwd'
```

I can use this user remotely from my JAVA code. When i run the code in the server, i got

```
Access denied for user 'test_user'@'test_host' (using password: YES)
```

I already ran `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` after grant all privileges for test_user and restarted the mysql service.

I tried to login mysql in the server using console

```
mysql -utest_user -ptest_passwd
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'test_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

It seems i can only using `test_user` remotely but not from the server itself. Any suggestions to fix this?

-------New test----------

I tried to do not provide password in the server, it is working

```
mysql -utest_user
```

I need to use password for both remotely and locally. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run into a similar problem before.

Having `%` should allow a user to connect from anywhere including localhost assuming you `granted privileges` and `flushed privileges`.  However, If you did not make a `secure install of mysql` you most likely have a `ghost localhost` left on your machine. So not only would you be able to just run `mysql` with no user, or password provided from localhost command line but the `ghost localhost` for some reason conflicts with any other users (besides root) that have been created from logging in on the `localhost`.

If you do `select user, password, host from mysql.user;` You will likely see a user with no name, no password and a host `localhost`.

Delete that user using `drop user ''@'localhost;`

`flush privileges` again.

Try to connect using your other user now on localhost and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
CREATE USER 'monty'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
```

and then

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'localhost'
    ->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

If it doesn't work, try logging in with root and see:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'admin'@'localhost';
```

Replace your values everywhere

Try this post:
[SO solution to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)

Comment: When you do: mysql -utest_user and then SHOW GRANTS, what does it show you?

Comment: Try the link I've added

Comment: i saw `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'test_user'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION`

Comment: Restart mysql server.

Comment: After removed `anonymous user`. The problem is solved. `DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User='';`